# Are terraform "loops" useless? Or am I missing something?

Tags: terraform

I wrote some configuration today that uses "loops", but only afterwards I wondered if this is the right path to go, since terraform keeps the resources in the state file as a list/array.

Consider the following configuration:

```
locals {
    users_list = [ "ab", "cd", "ef" ]
}

resource "aws_iam_user" "users" {
    count = "${length(local.users_list)}"
    name = "${local.users_list["${count.index}"]}"
    path = "/"
}
```

Running 'terraform apply' will create the users, and create the following resources in the state file:

- aws_iam_user.users[0]
- aws_iam_user.users[1]
- aws_iam_user.users[2]

But if, for example, I remove one of the first two users, like so:

```
locals {
        users_list = [ "cd", "ef" ]
}
```

then terraform will try to change the resources in the state file ( [0] --> "cd", [1] --> "ef" ), and the users themselves in AWS, which can be catastrophic, since every user will have his own keys, and doing so will create a mess. This is relevant to other resource types as well, although there are resources that deleting and creating again won't do such a mess, but still this is a wrong.

So, to my question, as in the title - maybe I got it all wrong? Or this is just the way it works? (making this whole "looping" mechanism useless)

Comment: What is exact problem caused by removing ab user in above case? Are keys being created in an array too?

Answer (score 3):

terraform before v0.11.x doesn't officially support loops in fact. The way to use with `count.index` as loops is coming from the blog [Terraform tips & tricks: loops, if-statements, and gotchas](https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9)

From version 0.12 (**still in beta currently**), it supports loops with new key word [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-12.html#attributes-vs-blocks), but I still don't guarantee if it fixes the problem in your question.

So I show the detail what the problem it is, and how to fix it, people like @Aniket Chopade can understand where this problem comes from.

After change the locals,

```
$ terraform apply -auto-approve
aws_iam_user.users[0]: Refreshing state... (ID: ab)
aws_iam_user.users[1]: Refreshing state... (ID: cd)
aws_iam_user.users[2]: Refreshing state... (ID: ef)
aws_iam_user.users[2]: Destroying... (ID: ef)
aws_iam_user.users[1]: Modifying... (ID: cd)
  name: "cd" => "ef"
aws_iam_user.users[0]: Modifying... (ID: ab)
  name: "ab" => "cd"
aws_iam_user.users[2]: Destruction complete after 2s

Error: Error applying plan:

2 error(s) occurred:

* aws_iam_user.users[0]: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_iam_user.users.0: Error updating IAM User ab: EntityAlreadyExists: User with name cd already exists.
    status code: 409, request id: 24853da7-452c-11e9-a853-bf4c89d8ebba
* aws_iam_user.users[1]: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_iam_user.users.1: Error updating IAM User cd: EntityAlreadyExists: User with name ef already exists.
    status code: 409, request id: 24839027-452c-11e9-b3d5-3deb12943195
```

I have to [taint](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/taint.html) these resources, mark them to be destroyed and apply again.

```
$ terraform taint aws_iam_user.users.1
The resource aws_iam_user.users.1 in the module root has been marked as tainted!

$ terraform taint aws_iam_user.users.0
The resource aws_iam_user.users.0 in the module root has been marked as tainted!

$ terraform apply -auto-approve
...
aws_iam_user.users[0]: Destroying... (ID: ab)
aws_iam_user.users[1]: Destroying... (ID: cd)
aws_iam_user.users[0]: Destruction complete after 2s
aws_iam_user.users[0]: Creating...
  arn:           "" => "<computed>"
  force_destroy: "" => "false"
  name:          "" => "cd"
  path:          "" => "/"
  unique_id:     "" => "<computed>"
aws_iam_user.users[1]: Destruction complete after 2s
aws_iam_user.users[1]: Creating...
  arn:           "" => "<computed>"
  force_destroy: "" => "false"
  name:          "" => "ef"
  path:          "" => "/"
  unique_id:     "" => "<computed>"
```

My conclusion is, in current situation, `taint` the resources to force terraform create new resources **if you change the order in a list**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As a workaround I would prefer to just change the array in the state (with `terraform state mv`) so the other users would left intact, and only the user I removed would be destroyed. But of course this is too messy.
Also, I'm not sure that the `for_each` (or `for`) loops in version 0.12 would help if the resource would will still be an array in the state file. The example in the link you provided is of dynamic clocks **inside** a resource.
I think the only way to achieve this is one of 2 ways: (on the next comment)

Comment: 1. Terraform should save the resources in the state file as a resource map/hash instead of an array, so it would know which user belongs where.
2. The resources will still be saved as an array, but terraform will do some calculations to understand if I just removed an item from the list.  
Maybe I'll open a feature request for that, but I'm not sure about the insides of terraform and if these options make sense at all.

Comment: @roeezab No, `terraform state mv` doesn't fix this issue at all. `terraform state rm` is  only used to clean the nominated resources from the tfstate file, but not really clean the resources in aws account. `taint` will mark the resources to be destroyed, so `terraform apply` will always destroy these tainted resources first, then apply the rest changes.

Comment: Agree to raise a feature/bug request to terraform team in GitHub for this directly.

Comment: This isn't strictly true. `count` was always officially used for creating multiple resources (otherwise what is the point of it) and that includes where an API doesn't have the concept of count to be passed to it (EC2 instances, for example, allow you to specify multiple instances that are created in a reservation in a single API call). 0.12 does add extra looping functionality inside resources and it will eventually replace the `count` syntax but `count` is still valid for resources. Also 0.12 will correctly handle removal of the non last elements in a `count` resource automatically.

Comment: @BMW `terraform state mv` works, I tested it now. If I want to remove user "cd", I switched between 1 and 2 in the state (by running 3 `state mv` commands), and after that the `apply` is just destroying the "cd" user, which I manually moved to be the last one on the array in the state file.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I tried now with terraform_0.12.0-beta1 and it works the same. Also, the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count-multiple-resource-instances) says:
Note that the separate resource instances created by count are still identified by their index, and not by the string values in the given list. This means that if an element is removed from the middle of the list, all of the indexed instances after it will see their subnet_id values change, which will cause more remote object changes than were probably intended.

Comment: Continue:
"The practice of generating multiple instances from lists should be used sparingly, and with due care given to what will happen if the list is changed later."
Probably should have read this before posting the question. So I wonder how much a feature request will help here...

Comment: ok one last comment (I hope :D). [This issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17179) is talking exactly about it.
TL;DR - it's the for_each feature, but they don't know yet when it will be released.