# Terraform with dynamic list will recreate ressources when index change

Tags: terraform

When using a dynamic list, if an entry is added or removed, every entry following the changed index will be updated.
How to have terraform insert only the new entry?

### Example

I have a list

- 10
- 20
- 30

*(terraform apply)*

Now change my list to add 15

- 10
- 15
- 20
- 30

*(terraform apply)*
Terraform is going to replace 20 -> 15, 30 -> 20 and create 30

### Simple solution

One solution is declaring every elements by themselves (not using a list)

### Complex workaround

Before applying, I could change directly the state file to change the indexes.
This seems dangerous.

### More context

I have a json data file with hundreds of dns entries.
I load that into a list using data.external

```
data "external" "read_dns_entries" {
   program = [ "${path.module}/terraform_script_dns_entries_from_file" ]
}

locals {
  file_dns_records_without_aliases = jsondecode(data.external.read_dns_entries.result.EntriesWithoutAlias)
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "record" {
  count = length(local.file_dns_records_without_aliases)

  zone_id         = local.file_dns_records_without_aliases[count.index].ZoneID
  name            = local.file_dns_records_without_aliases[count.index].Name
  type            = local.file_dns_records_without_aliases[count.index].Type
  allow_overwrite = true
  ttl             = local.file_dns_records_without_aliases[count.index].TTL
  records         = local.file_dns_records_without_aliases[count.index].Records

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

I am using `Terraform v0.12.18`

### References

This closed issue is talking about it.
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3449

This was hoping Terraform 0.12 would fix it with `for_each`
[Are terraform "loops" useless? Or am I missing something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132357/are-terraform-loops-useless-or-am-i-missing-something)

Comment: Another solution, I could also get existing entries, and make my list accordingly.
If I have something new: add it at the end.
But I still have the same problem if I need to remove the first entry => everything gets recreated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use Terraform 0.12.x or newer, consider opting for

1. `for_each` instead of `count`
2. a map instead of a list for input data representation (since `for_each` operates on maps)

One can compose a map from a list with the `{ for item in list: key => value }` expression (see https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions). As opposed to `count` which tracks resources by position, `for_each` tracks the representation of the resource in state by id (the map key). Since positions constantly change/shift as new resources are inserted or removed it is a rather flimsy structure to rely on. This is why one would notice many destroy/create operation upon a plan after a shuffl, insertion or removal in the resource list ;).

For the record, here is an snippet towards the cleaner setup:

```
data "external" "read_dns_entries" {
  program = ["${path.module}/terraform_script_dns_entries_from_file"]
}

locals {
  #file_dns_records_without_aliases = jsondecode(data.external.read_dns_entries.result.EntriesWithoutAlias)
  file_dns_records_without_aliases = {
    for entry in jsondecode(data.external.read_dns_entries.result.EntriesWithoutAlias) :
    entry.Name => entry
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "record" {
  # count = length(local.file_dns_records_without_aliases)
  for_each = local.file_dns_records_without_aliases

  zone_id         = each.value.ZoneID
  name            = each.value.Name
  type            = each.value.Type
  allow_overwrite = true
  ttl             = each.value.TTL
  records         = each.value.Records

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

P.S.: It seems like data.external is not quite idiomatically used here, and arguable using `file("${path.module}/terraform_script_dns_entries_from_file")` would be clearer as the intent is merely to read the contents of a file.

Comment: This is a perfect solution for my problem.
Indeed, I will use `for_each` more.
Thank you.